# Finding clashes using dictionary and sets Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I'm trying to figure out how to get clashes

```
nbr_dict  = {'key1': {1, 2, 3}, 'key2': {4, 5, 6}, 'key3': {1,5}}
```

I wanted it to look like

```
Clashes?: key1
key1 and key2: None
key1 and key3: 1

Clashes?: key2
key2 and key1: None
key2 and key3: 5

Clashes?: key3
key3 and key1: 1
key3 and key2: 5
```

Here is an example of my codes that I managed to get:

```
def main():
    nbr_dict  = {'key1': {1, 2, 3}, 'key2': {4, 5, 6}, 'key3': {1,5}}
    clashes = input('Clashes?: ')
    for key in sorted(nbr_dict):
        if key != clashes:
            print('{} and {}'.format(clashes, key))
            #I'm pretty sure all the arithmetic goes here#

main()
```

**Assume all the inputs given by the user is valid**

Comment: 1. what's the point of sorting the dict ? 2. you're comparing `key` with `clashes` but `key` in that context is an `int` while `clashes` is key1/key2/key3 - why would they *ever* be equal?

Comment: Answering your question, 1: Sorting it, if let say I added a new key with value, 'key0': {5,6} the output would be:                                 Clashes?: key1
key1 and key0:None
key1 and key2:None
key1 and key3:1                                                                       2.The key is a string actually, 'key1', 'key2' and etc or did you actually meant the values ? The not equal is to check if the key is equal to the clashes so that it will not give the output key1 and key1 or key2 and key2 or key3 and key3   Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `set` intersection, your data is already in sets:

```
def main():
    nbr_dict = {'key1': {1, 2, 3}, 'key2': {4, 5, 6}, 'key3': {1, 5}}
    clashes = input('Clashes?: ')
    if clashes in nbr_dict:
        target = nbr_dict[clashes]
        for k, v in nbr_dict.items():
            if k != clashes:
                # for raw data: `target & v`, the rest is just to match your desired output
                clash_values = [str(i) for i in target & v]
                print("{} and {}: {}".format(clashes, k, ", ".join(clash_values) or None))
    else:
        print("No such key: {}".format(clashes))

main()
```

.

```
Clashes?: key1
key1 and key3: 1
key1 and key2: None

Clashes?: key2
key2 and key3: 5
key2 and key1: None

Clashes?: key3
key3 and key2: 5
key3 and key1: 1

Clashes?: key4
No such key: key4
```

**EDIT**: If you need a sorted version, it's largely the same:

```
def main():
    nbr_dict = {'key1': {1, 2, 3}, 'key2': {4, 5, 6}, 'key3': {1, 5}}
    sorted_keys = sorted(nbr_dict.keys())  # lets get a nice list of sorted keys
    clashes = input('Clashes?: ')  # user input
    if clashes in nbr_dict:  # simple validation
        target = nbr_dict[clashes]  # this is our user selected set
        for k in sorted_keys:  # lets loop through our sorted keys
            if k != clashes:  # don't compare with the user selected key
                v = nbr_dict[k]  # this is our compare set
                # the same boilerplate from now on...
                clash_values = [str(i) for i in target & v]
                print("{} and {}: {}".format(clashes, k, ", ".join(clash_values) or None))
    else:
        print("No such key: {}".format(clashes))
```

You can further sort `clash_values` if the elements within the set intersections should be printed as sorted, too.

Answer (score 3):

You need intersection of sets.

```
for key, value in nbr_dict.items():
    if key != clashes:
        diff = nbr_dict[clashes] & value
            if len(diff):
                 print (key, diff)   # I leave you to figure out the formatting here
```

As already pointed out in the comment to the question, you do not need to sort your dictionary. However as pointed out by  MSeifert  you might still want to sort if the display order is important.

Comment: I think the sorting is there so the result is printed in the expected/required order.